# Error while Posting Data on linkedin?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, social-networking

I want to post data on linkedin for that i'm using share kit,

i was creating new application and i'm using those api key and secrete key in my application but when i click on login then it works fine button when i click on post button i'm getting error like below .

```
<error>
  <status>403</status>
  <timestamp>1362741300174</timestamp>
  <request-id>QK7HOT1CT3</request-id>
  <error-code>0</error-code>
  <message>Access to posting shares denied</message>
</error>
```

i don't know where i went wrong help me regarding this one ,thanks in advance.

Comment: please! check [this](http://getsharekit.com/docs/) may help you

Answer (score 4):

You have to request rw_nus permissions to your application to post a share..
check http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/share-api

**UPDATE**

The permission is `w_share`, check: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin, section: Permissions and Limits